# Spreedly gem with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreedly

I want to put spreedly in my new rails app.Because i am newbie can anyone help me with the spreedly gem?It says you must Configure your API key and site name for your account:

```
RSpreedly::Config.setup do |config|
  config.api_key        = "your-api-key"
  config.site_name      = "your-site-name"
end
```

Where  should i put that?I need to make a initializer for this?
And then i want to have a subscription system.Should i have to make a controller to  handle subscriptions?Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put that code in `config/initializers/spreedly.rb`.

Without knowing more about your application, it's hard to answer your second question, but I would say: yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Well i have a user model made with devise.In this model a i have a pro boolean.I want user to subscribe and get the pro boolean to true for a month.I think is simple implemetation!

Comment: Thanks Brandan!So i have to make this modeling whith the rspreedly gem!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be environment specific so you could do this in initializer

```
if Rails.env.development?
elseif Rails.env.test?
else
...
```

Or just put different values in test.rb, develoment.rb and production.rb